# Query runs in terminal but not in PHPMyadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am creating a trigger using this query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `log_after_delete`
AFTER DELETE ON author FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `author_log` VALUES (OLD.author_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END$$;
```

this query runs perfectly in terminal.

[image]

but when I tried with phpmyadmin, it shows error

[image]

Here is complete detail of Database server,webserver and phpmyadmin

[image]

Please suggest what is missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: after query you will found Delimiter there is `;` change to `//` and try it will work

Comment: I tred but no luck!! this is what I tried
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `log_after_delete`
 AFTER DELETE ON author FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `author_log` VALUES (OLD.author_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
 END $$
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CREATE TRIGGER `log_after_delete`
AFTER DELETE ON author FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `author_log` VALUES (OLD.author_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END
```

Then in phpmyadmin goto `sql` tab paste this query

And change the Delimiter there is `;` change to `//`
and go

Comment: It's not working. Can you please paste any trigger query here which is running successfully in phpmyadmin.